# Inherit environment variables in systemd Docker container

Tags: environment-variables, systemd, docker

I have a [Docker container running systemd](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/motiejus/systemd_fedora20/). I want to pass environment variables to applications under it.

When I start systemd from within Docker (`/sbin/init` as command line), Docker exposes variables to systemd, but *does not expose to child services*. If I add `systemd.setenv=...` to the cmdline, the variables are passed. I am looking for a cleaner solution.

How do I expose environment variables passed to `/sbin/init` to applications started by it?

```
% docker run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --privileged -ti \
             -e VAR1=1 motiejus/systemd_fedora20 \
             init systemd.setenv=VAR2=2
...
Welcome to Fedora 20 (Heisenbug)!
...
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.
[root@740690365eb0 ~]# env | grep VAR
VAR2=2
```

I expect to see `VAR1=1` while running my command.

In other words, can systemd pass variables passed to it to children it starts?

For Dockerfile, see [github repository](https://github.com/Motiejus/systemd_fedora20).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer the question asked (as it doesn't seem to be answered anywhere else)

> "How do I expose environment variables passed to /sbin/init to
>   applications started by it?"

requires some slightly irritating bash, and an extremely useful function of the linux /proc filesystem:

```
# Import our environment variables from systemd
for e in $(tr "\000" "\n" < /proc/1/environ); do
        eval "export $e"
done
```

This reads /proc/1/envion, which is the environment given to PID 1, but is delimited by nulls. It uses 'tr' to replace the nulls with new lines, and then iterates over those lines and evals them with a prepended 'export', so they are visible to child processes.

The not-exposing-environment-variables is yet another "feature" of systemd, and they don't consider it a bug.

Comment: I want to say 'I do not need this feature, I need environment variables'

Answer (score 2):

According to this description, a systemd user instance does not inherit environment variables:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Environment_variables

There is a suggestion here to use oneshot systemd service that configures an EnvironmentFile for the "final" service.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396167/how-do-i-get-etcd-values-into-my-systemd-service-on-coreos

Comment: Also consider to check `PassEnvironment=`. It helped me in docker systemd environment.